# How to use pointers

Tags: pointers, go

Let's say I have this function

```
func main() {
    x := 10
    change(&x)
}

func change(n *int) {

}
```

If I don't use in `n *int` the signature, the above function gives an error -

> *cannot use &x (type *int) as type int in argument to change*

But why does the below example run fine without requiring a client *HTTPClient in the argument of send method though I'm passing a pointer in this case?

```
import (
  "net/http"
)

// HTTPClient interface for making http requests
type HTTPClient interface {
    Get(url string) (*http.Response, error)
}


func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    err := send(client, url)
}

func send(client HTTPClient, url string) error {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTTPClient` is an interface, it defines a single method `Get(...)`

The client struct, from `http.Client` also has a get method, [docs here.](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get)

```
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    // trimmed ...
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/05f8b44d5edc2960eff106e5e780cf83535d0533/src/net/http/client.go#L391-L397)

You can see from the definition above that `Get(url)` has a "pointer receiver". This means that `*http.Client` defines the `Get(url)` method and **not** `http.Client`.  This means that `*httpClient` implements the `HTTPClient` interface and not `http.Client`.

The last thing worth pointing out is that the go runtime will automatically dereference pointers if, the an interface is implemented by a "value receiver" and not a "pointer receiver".

An example of this could be:

```
type Valuer interface {
    Value() string
}

type V struct {}

type (valueReceiver V) Value() string {
    // trimmed ...
}

// Here given a *V not V, go will dereference *V to call the Value() method on V not *V
vPtr := &V{}
vPtr.Value()
```

Answer (score 1):

`http.Client` has a Get method with a pointer receiver (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get), having the same signature as required by your `HTTPCLient` interface, so it works !

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a `HTTPClient` interface which takes a function `Get`. In go lang spec it is defined as

```
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    req, err := NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return c.Do(req)
}
```

In above function `*Client` is a pointer receiver to method `GET`. Client is a struct declared in [Go source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=12847:12907#L381). For more information on `http.Client` struct defined in `net/http` package Check out [Golang Spec](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client).

In your first example code you are passing a pointer to `Change` function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A interface{
    Change(n *int)
} 

func main() {
    x := 10
    Change(&x)
}

func Change(n *int) {
    fmt.Println(*n+1)
}
```

Check working example on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vATrnj3TJ5f)